# docker containers mapped to same port

Tags: apache-spark, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to setup a spark cluster using this link - https://github.com/actionml/docker-spark

When I created my container(2-worker and 1-master), I see all the ports being mapped to the same ports on the host.

I'm wondering how to access my master web ui for spark?

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                        NAMES
b54c5fd1442c        actionml/spark      "/entrypoint.sh wo..."   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        4040/tcp, 6066/tcp, 7001-7006/tcp, 7077/tcp, 8080-8081/tcp   spark-worker1
2c987a057223        actionml/spark      "/entrypoint.sh wo..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        4040/tcp, 6066/tcp, 7001-7006/tcp, 7077/tcp, 8080-8081/tcp   spark-worker0
b1d34441507e        actionml/spark      "/entrypoint.sh ma..."   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        4040/tcp, 6066/tcp, 7001-7006/tcp, 7077/tcp, 8080-8081/tcp   spark-master
```

Comment: Have you tried with `localhost:8080`?

Comment: How did you run the containers?

Comment: First, you have to expose port as mentioned by @yamenk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the README file of the repository, when starting master, you can specify the web ui port:

```
docker run --rm -it actionml/docker-spark master --webui-port PORT

--webui-port PORT  Port for web UI (default: 8080)
```

As you can see the default is 8080.

**However** you need to expose the port so that is it accessible:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm -it  actionml/docker-spark master
```

You can now open the browser and see the ui at `localhost:8080`